# Laravel Vagrant SQL backup

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have an issue getting SQL export from command line in vagrant virtual machine. I am trying with

```
mysql -u homestead -p db_name > dump.sql
```

But it freezes and nothing happens. More exact, it asks me for password, and after that it's just frozen. Ctrl+C/X don't interrupt the process but rather write the C sign and it won't quit. I have left the DB in that state for several hours, so it surely breaks somewhere. Can I debug the issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

With Homestead, you can login directly without password using `mysql`. If you need to make a dump, you just use `mysqldump -v your_database > file.sql` and it should works.

Notice the `-v` flag, it will help you to see what's happening during your dump :)